# Visual Studio C# reference-warning

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, reference, warnings

After compiled, my solution has a warning as below snapshot.
[image]

Double clicking the warning will popup a question which I have no idea what it is.
[image]

If you understand what VS is talking about, please share.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like you've referenced slightly different versions of your dependencies in different projects in your solutions.  What this means is that when you try and run your projects you may get unexpected errors if you pass any references with types in the dependencies as types from different versions of the same assembly are considered to be different.

E.g.

Project1 uses dependency `SomeAssembly.dll` which is Version 1.0
Project2 uses dependency `SomeAssembly.dll` but at Version 1.1
Project2 has Project1 as a dependency

Code in project 2 tries to pass a reference of `SomeType` where that type is defined in `SomeAssembly.dll` from its code to code from project 1.  Project 1 throws an error because the type is not recognised as it comes from a different version of the assembly.

Your problem may be more subtle than this since most errors of this type can be caught by the compiler but if you have complex dependencies or use dependency injection the compiler may not necessarily spot things like this.

Visual Studio is offering to effectively do a workaround for you my redirecting the dependencies all to a specific version.  IMHO I would avoid taking the fix if you can fix it manually yourself.

You would be much better off going through your solution and checking all your references to ensure they all match version wise.  You may need to remove and add back references to get this working properly but doing this now will avoid unexpected problems in the long run.

Comment: Almost agree to choose yours as accepted answer. Would you please give a brief example of the part `if you pass any references with types in the dependencies as types from different versions of the same assembly are considered to be different`. Thank you!